# Do I need to delete the object?

Tags: c++

If I use `new` operator to create a object like this in a method:

```
void functionA(){
    ClassA *a = new ClassA();
}
```

Do I need to use the following code to release it?

```
   delete a;
```

Can c++ auto release the ClassA object's memory? when it run out of the functionA scope.

If I write codes like this

```
void functionA(){
    ClassA a = ClassA();
}
```

Does a automatically be released?

Comment: This is something that is answered in any good [beginner book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: I think yes, because C++ doesn't have auto garbage collection

Comment: @pinkpanther, It does, it's called RAII. And C++11 has support for GC.

Comment: @chris but is that default?, is that an external library? I'm talking about with out third party libraries

Comment: @pinkpanther, The standard library has great RAII options. There's no real *need* for a GC with RAII, but the support is there if you'd rather have that.

Comment: @pinkpanther: C++11 doesn't *actually* support GC in a generally useful way. It defines parameters for what a GC can do, *if* one exists, and defines some functions for interacting with it.  In all common standard library implementations, as far as I know, these functions are no-ops.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For:

```
void functionA() {
    ClassA *a = new ClassA();
}
```

You must place `delete a;` inside the function to clean it:

```
void functionA() {
    ClassA *a = new ClassA();
    // your other code here
    delete a;
}
```

Otherwise you will face a memory leak. This is unless you return the `a` variable somehow or pass it to some other place that frees it.

For:

```
void functionA(){
    ClassA a = ClassA();
}
```

`a` will get 'released' automatically if you define its destructor properly. It is still possible that some field inside `a` leak if  you do not properly clean up in the `ClassA` destructor.

Comment: And please note that the semantics of `Class a = ClassA()` are almost certainly different than what the OP expects.

Answer (score 3):

> Do I need to use the following code to release it?

Yes, you have to release every `new` ed object.

> Can c++ auto release the ClassA object's memory?

You could use *smart pointers*:

```
#include <memory>

void functionA(){
    std::unique_ptr<ClassA> a_ptr(new ClassA);
}
```

Memory allocated for `a_ptr` will be automatically realeased once `a_ptr` goes out of scope.

> If I write codes like this
>
> ```
> void functionA(){
>     ClassA a = ClassA();
> }
> ```
>
> Does a automatically be released?

Yes, it does.

Answer (score 3):

```
void functionA(){
    ClassA a = ClassA();
}
```

Uhm, why write that? It's inefficient, confusing and completely unnecessary. What's wrong with:

```
void functionA() {
    ClassA a;
}
```

Generally speaking, if you use `new` you must use `delete` when you no longer need the instance that you allocates with `new`. There are exceptions to that, of course, but you don't need to worry about them now. For now just remember: if you allocated it, with `new` you own it and must deallocate it with `delete`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`std::unique_ptr`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/unique_ptr/) to do this automatically:

```
void functionA() {
    std::unique_ptr<ClassA> a(new ClassA());
    // don't release
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to delete any dynamically allocated raw pointer. If you want to destroy it automatically when going out of scope, you can use some smartpointer included in C++11 standard like [`shared_ptr`][1] or [`unique_ptr`][2] or [`scoped_ptr`][3] in boost library:

```
 [1]: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/unique_ptr/
 [2]: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/shared_ptr/
 [3]: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/smart_ptr/scoped_ptr.htm
```